# How to set the number of intervals in an elasticsearch histogram

Tags: histogram, elasticsearch, faceted-search, facet

Using elasticsearch, I'd like to get a histogram facet for a price field in my model. Without knowing beforehand the min and max prices, what I'd like is to have the histogram cover the entire range of prices, with a set number of intervals, say 10. I can see from the documentation at

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/search/facets/histogram-facet.html

that I can specify the price range for each interval, but this would give me some unspecified number of intervals. I'd like to have some specific number of intervals that evenly cover the entire range of values for the price field. Is there any way to do this?

I know that one solution could be to query my database for the min and max values, and then figure out the appropriate interval size, but that goes against one of the main points of using elasticsearch, which is to not have to hit the db for search related queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query elasticsearch for min and max values using [Statistical Facet](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/search/facets/statistical-facet.html)

Comment: ah, so you're saying do two queries against ES? Is there any way to do it in one query?

Comment: Yes, I don't think it's possible to do using a single query. When elasticsearch is processing facets on different shards, it needs to know which bucket each facet belongs and buckets have to be the same across all shards. So, even if this query was implemented in elasticsearch, elasticsearch would have to perform two queries internally - first it would have to figure out the min and max value across all shards and then calculate number of facets in each bucket.

Answer (score 0):

You can track progress on the implementation of this feature, referred to as `auto_histogram`, at https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/31828